# Installing draft apk from google play

Tags: android, air, apk

I am working on an Adobe air based Android app. Since it's over 50MB, I have a separate obb file. At the moment my app is not published, still there as draft, and I need to test the obb downloading functionnalities before moving on.

So, does anyone know of any way to download an app from the store that is there as draft? I tried adding my own google group to the testers list, but it seems like a publish is required as well.

Am I just missing something about the draft mode? It seems pretty useless if you can't even make sure that what you uploaded is actually functionnal before publishing.